# using Julia 1.0 findmax equivalent of numpy.argmax

Tags: julia

In Julia I want to find the column index of a matrix for the maximum value in each row, with the result being a `Vector{Int}`. Here is how I am doing it currently (`Samples` has 7 columns and 10,000 rows):

```
mxindices = [ i[2] for i in findmax(Samples, dims = 2)[2]][:,1]
```

This works but feels rather clumsy and verbose.  Wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer about seven thousand times. I think I'm done now :-)

Comment: If my answer is helpful and complete, then please consider up-voting and marking the question answered (click the tick mark next to my response).

Comment: I would probably go with `mapslices`: `mapslices(row -> findmax(row)[2], Samples, dims=[2])[:,1]`

Answer (score 4):

Even simpler: Julia has an `argmax` function and Julia 1.1+ has an `eachrow` iterator.  Thus:

```
map(argmax, eachrow(x))
```

Simple, readable, and fast — it matches the performance of Colin's `f3` and `f4` in my quick tests.

Comment: Or: `argmax.(eachrow(Samples))`

Comment: Broadcast won't be quite as efficient here since `eachrow` is just an iterator and so broadcast currently collects it into an array before using it — that's something I want to improve in the future but for now it's going to perform worse.

Comment: Also if you're stuck on Julia 1.0, note that the `eachrow` definition we're using here is super simple! You can just add it to your project on an ad-hoc basis: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/92271ea56b0da2b34fbd0c83f76a24e9156fb7bd/base/abstractarraymath.jl#L421

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** For the sake of completeness, I've added Matt B.'s excellent solution to the test-suite (and I also forced the `transpose` in `f4` to generate a new matrix rather than a lazy view).

Here are some different approaches (yours is the base-case `f0`):

```
f0(x) = [ i[2] for i in findmax(x, dims = 2)[2]][:,1]
f1(x) = getindex.(argmax(x, dims=2), 2)
f2(x) = [ argmax(vec(x[n,:])) for n = 1:size(x,1) ]
f3(x) = [ argmax(vec(view(x, n, :))) for n = 1:size(x,1) ]
f4(x) = begin ; xt = Matrix{Float64}(transpose(x)) ; [ argmax(view(xt, :, k)) for k = 1:size(xt,2) ] ; end
f5(x) = map(argmax, eachrow(x))
```

Using `BenchmarkTools` we can examine the efficiency of each (I've set `x = rand(100, 200)`):

```
julia> @btime f0($x);
  76.846 μs (13 allocations: 4.64 KiB)

julia> @btime f1($x);
  76.594 μs (11 allocations: 3.75 KiB)

julia> @btime f2($x);
  53.433 μs (103 allocations: 177.48 KiB)

julia> @btime f3($x);
  43.477 μs (3 allocations: 944 bytes)

julia> @btime f4($x);
  73.435 μs (6 allocations: 157.27 KiB)

julia> @btime f5($x);
  43.900 μs (4 allocations: 960 bytes)
```

So Matt's approach is the fairly obvious winner, as it appears to just be a syntactically cleaner version of my `f3` (the two probably compile to something very similar, but I think it would be overkill to check that).

I was hoping `f4` might have an edge, despite the temporary created via instantiating the `transpose`, since it could operate on the columns of a matrix rather than the rows (Julia is a column-major language, so operations on columns will always be faster since the elements are synchronous in memory). But it doesn't appear to be enough to overcome the disadvantage of the temporary.

Note, if it is ever the case that you want the full `CartesianIndex`, that is, both the row and column index of the maximum in each row, then obviously the appropriate solution is just `argmax(x, dims=2)`.

Comment: Can do `last.` rather than `getindex.` though idk if that is clearer.

Comment: @LyndonWhite I get a method error on `lastindex(::CartesianIndex{2})` on v1.1. Admittedly, I'm surprised by that. `CartesianIndex` is an iterable right so it *should* have a `lastindex` method...

Comment: @LyndonWhite Well, I just tried to iterate a `CartesianIndex` and I got: `ERROR: iteration is deliberately unsupported for CartesianIndex. Use I rather than I..., or use Tuple(I)...`, so obviously there is a good reason for the current behaviour. I did like your `last` idea, but if you have to add a `Tuple` in there too then I don't think it is syntactically any clearer :-)

Comment: The iteration thing is intentional, the `lastindex` thing I do not think is. `idx[end]` makes sense as a thing to do. Would you care to raise an issue?

Comment: `transpose`  does not create another matrix, but just a *lazy* view.

Comment: @hckr Good point. I forced the temporary but it made things worse :-)

Comment: @LyndonWhite I asked about this on Discourse but didn't get a response from anyone (and it has been over a week now)...

Comment: Issues belong on github, not on discourse. Even potential issues that get rapidly closed as being features, or stemming from user error still belong on GitHub

Comment: @LyndonWhite I actually did start at the GitHub issues page, but was put off by the default banner: `If you have a question or are unsure if the behavior you're experiencing is a bug, please search or post to our Discourse site`. I've opened an issue now [#31815](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/31815)

Answer (score 0):

Mapslices function is also a great option for this problem:

```
julia> Samples = rand(10000, 7);

julia> res = mapslices(row -> findmax(row)[2], Samples, dims=[2])[:,1];

julia> res[1:10]
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 1
 3
 5
 4
 4
 1
 4
 5
 3
```

Although this is a lot slower than what Colin suggested above, it might be more readable for some people. This is essentially exactly the same code as you started out with, but uses `mapslices` instead of list comprehensions.